# Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

I am running a simple program and trying to print the output of a file using **sc** but when I run the program in pycharm it's giving below

> The system cannot find the path specified.

But the path I have given is correct and also another exception is popping up don't know how to solve the issue

[image: PFA]

Here is the code I am trying

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
sc = SparkContext(master="local", appName="Spark_demo")
filePath = "D:\discuss\text.txt"
print(sc.textFile(filePath).first())
```

Comment: Can anyone able to identify the solution plz help

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue... There was an issue with pyspark setup and also its path variables.. open command prompt as administrator and check **pyspark** running or not if it is working then run the pycharm project.